# Proper way to tie a user to firestore collection?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a budget app in android using Firebase Firestore. I am able to create and login users to the app. I am able to create a generic "document" with the following code:

```
    final String userID = currentUser.getUid();
    Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
    userMap.put("userID", userID);
    database.collection("Users").document(userID).set(userMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d("ADDED USER:", "User " + userID + " added to db");
                    }
                });
```

Is this the proper way to start a user specific database in Firestore? And can I flatten it out to where the collection is the uses the user id?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Trying to figure this our myself.

Answer (score -5):

You have not checked the documentation properly. It clearly states as how you can create a user using various login methods. And then push data accordingly for each user.

Manage users here like authentication, pushing, retrieving data:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: I can create the user accounts in my app. But the documentation does not clearly state how to tie the user account to a "collection" or "document" in Cloud Firestore.